# Method to go in which class?

Tags: oop

I have 2 classes, player and game and a method called get_player_games($player_id). Which class does this method belong to?

I seem to run into this problem a bit, where I'm not 100% sure which class the method should go in. Is it just a matter of preference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it as:

**Game**

Class Game stores information about a game.
Game includes current game details such as score, players (in game), and other details.
There may be one or more games at one time.

**Player**

Class Player stores information about a player in a game.
Player includes details about the player, such as name, UID, contact, and other details.

So, if you need a player's list of current games, you need to have a list of games, and a list to store players. This feels like a static method.

So... Where does it go? I would say in neither Game nor Player class. Why not a Games class? One that...

- Referenced current games (and associated players)
- High score charts
- Game histories (who has played, when, how long, etc...)

So, to me, you need a Games class that allowed you to statically call lists of information related to what games were in progress, who is playing, high score lists, etc...

Comment: How would you propose associating players and games in the "games" class?  If we have lists of players and a list of games, how do we get the games for player A?

Comment: Unless they are living in memory only and not somehow capable of being cross-referenced, I assume there is a database of some kind. If Player A is a detail of Game 1, 4, 15, and 25, "SELECT GameID FROM Games WHERE Players = "%PlayerA%".

Comment: It seems that the ability to cross reference may be important here.  I worry about the extra class possibly leading to over-architecting.  What I was asking is that if you have a list of players and a list of games, how do you store the data in the class so that you know which players go with which game.  This isn't a database question, but a way to determine how using a class "Games" solves this problem?

Comment: And I'm saying, why do you have to "store the data in the class"? It's a simple function to cross-reference one entity to another. The "method" in which you do so is based on the logical way in which the system is constructed. Why should a Player object be aware of what games it is involved in, unless it were manually made aware (through registering or databasing)? If you are doing that, then a Games object is not too far off. Either way, if a Player object can register a game, a Games object could just as easily provide a referential data pointer to said game, with the actual data available.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typical cross-reference sort of situation -- to be completely objective, it can go in either class.  It really is a matter of preference, assuming that a player can have multiple games and a game can be associated with multiple players.

That said, I've always approached it philosophically from the way you're inclined to name the method in the first place -- get_player_games() sounds like you're interested in the games for a particular player. The player is the subject of interest (based on the limited English-style grammar of the method name), the games happened to be the detail associated with that.  If you had said get_game_players() or get_games_for_player(), then I would say that the games are the subject of interest, not the player.

Obviously, I'm biased by the noun you chose first (again, from a biased English grammar point of view), but since you can argue that the method belongs in either class, it's the only possible basis to use in such a case.

Again, it's somewhat of an arbitrary decision, but I've always been inclined to follow what the method naming rhetorically suggests to me about in which class it belongs.

Comment: +1 I really like the English semantics approach.  This is really what object oriented programming is about, using nouns to describe objects and verbs to describe the actions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to think of it:  A game can have 1 player.  A game can have 2 players.  A game can have N players.  Does that sound good?

How about this:  A player can be a part of 1 game.  A player can be a part of 2 games.  A player can be a part of N games.

Now, think about how your application is architected.  Which one of the above works best?  The answer largely depends on whether or not it's a one to many relationship between games and players, a one to many relationship between players and games.

Of course, if it's a many to many relationship, then both classes may need that method.

Comment: Just to touch on this answer, you may want to write two methods; get_player_games($player_id), which would go into your 'games' class, and get_player_games(), which would go into your 'player' class that uses its own id within the method body.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a `Game` object models a single game, then the method clearly does not belong there as any given game would have no knowledge of other games.  It is conceivable that a `Player` object could keep a list of all games in which the player has participated.  But the way you have phrased the question suggests that we don't have a reference to a `Player` object but rather only a player ID.  Therefore, `Player` doesn't work either.

It sounds like that method would belong on a class named `MatchHistory` or `Tournament` or `Ladder` or something like that.